# Avoid boilerplate code to setup UI in viewDidLoad

Tags: swift

i am just wondering how did you properly setup your UI in your IOS developments with Swift. Generally, I feel like I need to put a lot of statements in viewDidLoad lifecycle method of a view controller to customize UI elements. I know that I can use storyboard to help to setup those UI elements but sometimes we need to make some adjustments programmatically. Those adjustments resulting in a huge and boilerplate code in viewDidLoad. **So, how do you handle this ? Did your use extensions only for the UI part ? Specific classes ? How you can clearly separate UI from logic ?**

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom view for it!

If you find yourself writing a lot of this kind of code:

```
myView.someProperty1 = someValue1
myView.someProperty2 = someValue2
myView.someProperty3 = someValue3
myView.someProperty4 = someValue4
myView.someProperty5 = someValue5
myView.addSubView(subView1)
myView.addSubView(subView2)
myView.addSubView(subView3)
...
```

and the values that you give the properties are all independent of the view controller, it might be time to create a custom view.

Here is an example:

Create an `xib` file for your view, and name it the same name as your custom view. You will be adding the subviews of your custom view and all the constraints you need here.

And then you can do something like this:

```
@INDesignable // add this if you want to see your view drawn on the storyboard!
class MyCustomView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var subView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var subView2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var subView3: UIImageView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        let view = viewFromNibForClass()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [
            UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth,
            UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
        ]
        addSubview(view)
        // set up your view here...
        // set all the properties and stuff
    }

    private func viewFromNibForClass() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: MyCustomView.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, the custom view can be `@IBDesignable` which makes things really nice in the storyboard.

Comment: You should not use `Bundle.main`, you should always use `Bundle(for:)`, otherwise you will be seeing strange problems in interface builder or when putting the code into a library.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks, I kind of rarely put stuff on the storyboard. I don't know if it's a bug or is it my problem, but Xcode 8's IB is always acting a little weirdly...

Comment: I always thought IB was acting weirdly on Xcode 7 but when I got to really debug the problems, mostly they were caused in my code. Actually, using `Bundle.main` was usually the biggest problem. IB works rather reliably for me.

Comment: @Sweeper  what is a xib file and how do you create it ?

Comment: It's like a mini storyboard, but storyboards are for view controllers, xibs are for views. Go to File->New->File and in the "User Interface" section, select `Empty`. @Arrabidas92